# Creating JSON object with a multiple child nodes

Tags: java, json, jackson, data-conversion

I am trying to create a JSON object in Java. Object structure looks like this:

```
{
  "a" : {
    "b" : {
      "c" : {
        "d" : [ {
          "value" : false
        } ]
      }
    },
    "id" : "123"
  },
  "type" : "test"
}
```

I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` and usually I just create a corresponding domain objects that can be converted to JSON string using `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString()` method.

The problem is that in order to match the JSON structure above I will have to create a bunch of domain objects with only one field and on top of that creating a complete JSON object will involve a lot of boilerplate code just to set 2 or 3 JSIN properties.

I am wondering if there is a better approach that I am not familiar with. Maybe, using JSONPath or another library.

Comment: You should probably take a look at org.json. It has a simple api to create json objects

Answer (score 1):

Gson (`com.google.gson`) allows to register custom Serializer, Deserializers and TypeAdapters, with which you can handle a structure without boilerplate classes. This allows for a better conversion from JSON-DTOs to your actual Domain Objects.

See here for an example: https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide

(I'm also quite interested in additional answers to this question.)